# How can I force all program threads to exit on program close?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How can I ensure that all program threads abort after I have closed the main window?

Comment: Are the threads set as background threads?

Comment: Avoid fire-and-forget threading.  Environment.Exit() is the Q&D solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- If you have designed the threading well, you should have a mechanism to close them - e.g. use a `ManualResetEvent` to signal them to close
- You can Thread.Join to wait until they close, or Thread.Abort to have them abort in a nasty way
- If they are background threads, they will close when the app does

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I'll add the standard comment - never use abort (do a search here on S/O to see all the details as to why it's a very bad idea).

Comment: Do read up on why though, because in most cases it's a perfectly acceptable compromise.  "Never use abort" is wrong I'm afraid.

Comment: Fair point. How about don't do it unless you understand the arguments against and you don't have an alternative.

Answer (score 18):

You can set the "IsBackground" Property to true. The CLR closes all background threads when the application exits.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
Application.ExitThread();
Environment.Exit(0);
```

or

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Thread.Abort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect them somewhere, such as

```
static public List<Thread> AllThreads;
```

and use that collection to `.Abort()` them, one by one.

This is the *HARD* and *WRONG* way.  Better would be to signal them to stop somehow, and then `.Join()` one by one.

Comment: Do you mean `.Abort()`?  `.Terminate` does not exist

Comment: Also, if you have a list, why not `AllThreads.ForEach(t => t.Abort());`?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone when I said terminate them one by one, that is exactly what I meant.  Lambda, or not, you are terminating them one-by-one.

Comment: I just figured an actual example would be ideal, just a suggestion :)

Comment: Yeah, it's cool. I like lambdas, but are somehow difficult to debug.  Anyway, OP should use .Abort() only if is lazy and has no other means of stopping the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `IsBackground` property to true,and add the following lines:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CloseMe; // for the main process
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += CloseMe; // for ApplicationDomains
```

Let the `CloseMe` method set a flag which is checked in the main loop of the thread.

Answer (score -2):

By letting the program actually close, ie. dont deliberately introduce any code that forces the thread that runs the main window to wait for any other threads. The thread that runs the main window will then be free to exitProcess() and the OS will then abort all other threads in your process, no matter what they are doing.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: By default on .NET, threads that are not background will mean the app won't simply 'close'.  If you call ExitProcess (which is called Environment.Exit in the .NET world), that would work